# Spring Kafka Batch Listener Application Restart

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am testing a Spring Kafka batch listener, Batch ack mode , polling 3 records at a time and persisting those records to database. When Spring Boot application is restarted I see another 3 records being consumed and processed.

What if the batch size is larger (500) and the records could not be persisted to database before the shut down process has finished? How do we make sure those messages are not lost or handle this scenario?

```
2021-09-21 22:37:22,448 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]  com.example.demo.kafka.CassandraConsumer:  processing batch size: 3, starting partition: 0, offset: 2797145
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55506', transport: 'socket'
2021-09-21 22:38:02,388 WARN  [HikariPool-1 housekeeper]  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$HouseKeeper: HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=48s84ms).
2021-09-21 22:38:02,393 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]  com.example.demo.kafka.CassandraConsumer: batch update -> 39.943579103
2021-09-21 22:38:02,494 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]  com.example.demo.kafka.CassandraConsumer:  processing batch size: 3, starting partition: 0, offset: 2797148
2021-09-21 22:38:02,495 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]  com.example.demo.kafka.CassandraConsumer: batch update -> 7.52304E-4
```

Answer (score 0):

The offsets won't be committed unless the listener exits normally - as long as you are using a recent, supported, version with the default error handler (`SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`).